# How to have ssh running in the rescue mode?

Tags: ssh, upstart, rescue-mode

If I select rescue mode in GRUB, ssh is not run. I have to type `start ssh` to have it running. Can I made this be done automatically for me?

Typical situation is with broken graphics, when I need to login to the box remotely. Now, I have to type `start ssh` blindly first and hope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your system starts into the rescue mode, it uses the so called single user mode. This is runlevel 1. You'll find all programs which start here in `/etc/rc1.d` (starting with `S`).

You have to add ssh to runlevel 1. You can do this by making a symlink from `/etc/init.d/ssh` to `/etc/rc1.d/S99ssh`. The command `update-rc.d` assists you here. If you need a graphical program you can use `bum` (boot up manager).

Comment: Not sure if your answer applies to upstart (check page title and tags), but with ubiquitous systemd now, usptart is obsolete anyway. Thanks for answer.